# AngularJS - how to wait for templates being loaded before event is fired

Tags: angularjs, templates, asynchronous

Simply put my case is that I fire an event from the run phase. In several directives I listen to this event and execute code. The problem is that on my development machine some directives get the template via the templateUrl property before compiling the directive. Because of this it will miss the event. This behaviour can be reproduced with the $locationChangeSuccess event.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('directiveOne', function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: '/some/url.html',
        controller: function($rootScope){
            $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(){
                console.log('Directive one callback');
            });
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('directiveTwo', function(){
    return {
        template: '<div></div>',
        controller: function($rootScope){
            $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(){
                console.log('Directive two callback');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

In this code you will see only the second log message being logged where I would expect both of the directives to log a message.

How would one overcome this issue? I know I can make a build that adds the template to the $templateCache but this is my development machine and I do not want to make a build each time.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this problem, you will need to understand the lifecycles of angular's directive **AND** the architecture of `ui-router`.

The catch is `template` and `templateUrl` of angular's directive. And what makes this more interesting you are listening to the `$locationChangeSuccess` in the controller function of the directive.

So the answer is it is because directive loads its `templateUrl` **asynchronously**. What this means is that angular does not wait for the templateUrl to be fully loaded (because if it does, it will stall the whole bootstrapping process). So it continues to traverse down the DOM nodes, and continue whatever it should do in the pipeline. This of course includes, loading the controllers, and fire events, go into a particular states, etc.

Now if the broadcast of `$locationChangeSuccess` fires **before** the directive is fully loaded, it will miss this particular event, and hence, your will miss the console.log

However, if there are new `$locationChangeSuccess` happens again **after** the directive is loaded (including finish fetching the templateUrl, instantiate its own scope, etc), then yes, your console log should catch it again.

I believe in your example, there `$locationChangeSuccess` only happened once, and that is during the initial load of your app whereby the url is instantiated. If you actually force another `$locationChangeSuccess` after the DOM is loaded, your first directive will be able to catch that broadcast event, again.

On the same token, why `template = "<div></div>"` will work is because the directive does not need to fetch it asynchronously, hence compile on the spot, and the DOM renders before the `$locationChangeSuccess` event, and is able to console log the message.

To demontstrate my answer, I have created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LUqLsNZERp7XDFAn1ueY?p=preview). I am using `$stateChangeSuccess` in the plnkr, but you got the gist. Here, I manually fire another `stateChange` via a button click, and this happens **after** the directive is loaded. Voila, it catches the broadcast!

TLDR: `templateUrl` was fetched asynchronously, and it was late to catch on to the train of `locationChangeSuccess`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer but unfortunately you only explained why it was happening and I was already aware of that. The question was more; how to overcome something like this in a nice way.

Comment: I think it is quite impossible for that at the moment, since directives are only loaded when the controller is loaded, which is when the state has already entered. I bet you gonna miss the first broadcast buddy :(

Comment: I'm afraid so to. But I thought...maybe some good ideas pop up when I put it on SO. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Directives are loaded lazily. I don't believe angular will evaluate any of your directives during the run phase. Can you elaborate on your requirements?

Comment: yes I can. I grab the current url and parse it to make a 'state' object of it. This state object is leading for  my app to determine what to load so directives listen to a 'statechange' event which I pass on that created object so it knows what to do. I initialize this from the run phase.

Comment: It does sound to me like you're reinventing the angularjs ui router?

Comment: It is basically something like that indeed... but ui-router has to much in it that I do not use and missing things I need. So I need to do something like it myself.